# Is it possible to use Sparkle in Qt (Golang bindings) app?

Tags: qt, go, auto-update, sparkle

We build a Qt app using: https://github.com/therecipe/qt.
Now we need an auto updater and found this: https://sparkle-project.org

Looks like it is being used by multiple apps on my machine:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
/Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
/Applications/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
...
```

Some articles show me how to use it in Qt:

- http://www.discoversdk.com/knowledge-base/using-sparkle-in-qt
- https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/1137#issuecomment-336667547

but it's for C++/Objective C code.

Is it possible to use with Golang? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/therecipe/qt/issues/743#issuecomment-444689169

sparkle.m:

```
#import <Headers/SUUpdater.h>

static SUUpdater* updater = nil;

void sparkle_checkUpdates()
{
    if (!updater) {
        updater = [[SUUpdater sharedUpdater] retain];
    }

    [updater setUpdateCheckInterval:3600];
    [updater checkForUpdatesInBackground];
}
```

sparkle.go:

```
// +build darwin windows

package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I ${SRCDIR}/Sparkle.framework
#cgo LDFLAGS: -F ${SRCDIR} -framework Sparkle

void sparkle_checkUpdates();
*/
import "C"

func sparkle_checkUpdates() {
    C.sparkle_checkUpdates()
}
```

And in `main.go`, call that func:

```
action := widgets.NewQMenuBar(nil).AddMenu2("").AddAction("Check for Updates...")
// http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#MenuRole-enum
action.SetMenuRole(widgets.QAction__ApplicationSpecificRole)
action.ConnectTriggered(func(bool) { sparkle_checkUpdates() })
```

appcast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<rss xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Premium VPN</title>
    <item>
      <title>1.0.0.2905</title>
      <pubDate>Tue, 11 Dec 2018 11:09:10 +0800</pubDate>
      <sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>10.7</sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>
      <enclosure url="https://example.com/x.zip" sparkle:version="1.0.0.2905" sparkle:shortVersionString="1.0.0.2905" sparkle:edSignature="$(/path/to/Sparkle/bin/sign_update)" length="104408678" type="application/octet-stream"/>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>SUFeedURL</key>
<string>https://example.com/appcast.xml</string>
<key>SUPublicEDKey</key>
<string>$(/path/to/Sparkle/bin/generate_keys)</string>
```